# Arduino If Statement Clarification

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

Need help with this code. It says error compiling for board. I know the problem is in the if statement.

I'm trying to program if the distance from the ultrasound is between 1 and 150 cm, send a tone to the piezo, else I want it to continue with the main loop.

```cpp
// Include the library:
#include <NewPing.h>

// Define Trig, Echo pin and Piezo pin:
#define trigPin 3
#define echoPin 5
#define piezoPin 9

// Define maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-600 cm:
#define MAX_DISTANCE 400

// NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.
NewPing sonar = NewPing(trigPin, echoPin, MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
  // Open the Serial Monitor at 9600 baudrate to see ping results:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
    
void loop() {
  // Wait 1s between pings. 29ms should be the shortest delay between pings:
  delay(1000);

  // Measure distance and print to the Serial Monitor:
  Serial.print("Distance = ");

  // Send ping, get distance in cm and print result (0 = outside set distance range):
  Serial.print(sonar.ping_cm()); 
  Serial.println(" cm");

  if ((sonar.ping_cm() >= 1) && (sonar.ping_cm() <= 150)) {
    tone(piezoPin, 1000, 500);
  } else { 
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: NewPing and tone() want to use the same timer

Answer (score 0):

As @Juraj mentioned, possibly `tone` and `NewPing.h` use the same resources from the AVR.

Particularly, the `NewPing.h` [library](https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/src/master/src/NewPing.h) uses timer interrupts.

I would suggest trying with a short PWM pulse for driving the piezo instead of using `tone`.

Try with different PWM-capable pins. [Here](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-tutorial7-piezo-beep) you have one example of how to do it. You could adapt it to your needs.